# First div is sitting inside my nav bar?

Tags: html, css

I'm at a loss here for some reason my fist divs on my page are bleeding into and sitting inside the nav bar div? I've checked closing divs, and tried to rewrite the code. I'd love to understand WHY this is occurring!

It's not obvious to me, and I'm not sure where to go next.

Thank you

[image: What is wrong jumbotron is in navbar]

```
<!DOCTYPE  html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">

    <!--BOOTSTRAP link to bootstrap stylesheet | v4.1 | 30May18-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--BOOTSTRAP JS import link to bootstrap stylesheet | v4.1 | 04Jun18-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <style>
    /*Navbar styling*/
        .navbar {
            background-color: #8A84E2;
        }
        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
            {
            font-family: Georgia;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 30px;
        }
        h2 {
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        h3 {
            font-size: 10px;
        }
        p,
        ol,
        ul {
            font-size: 16px;
            font-family: calibri;
        }
        section {
            padding: 10px;
        }
        .myContent {
            padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>


<body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

    <!--Navbar copied and adapted via bootstrap-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.html">
                <img src="styles/images/LCicon.png" width="50" height="50">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About
                            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            100DaysOfCode
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="100-days-all-pages/1-blog.html">1: This Blog</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="100-days-all-pages/1-blog.html#day1">2. CSS Koala</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="100-days-all-pages/1-blog.html#day2">3. Laravel</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="100-days-all-pages/1-blog.html#day4">4. Updates &amp; FCC</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="100-days-all-pages/1-blog.html#day5">5. </a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="100-days-all-pages/1-blog.html#day6">6. </a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="100-days-all-pages/1-blog.html#day7">7. </a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="100-days-all-pages/1-blog.html#day8">8. </a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="100-days-all-pages/1-blog.html#day9">9. </a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="100-days-all-pages/1-blog.html#day10">10. </a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="100-days-all-pages/1-blog.html#day11">11. </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--End Nav-->

    <!--Jumbotron-->
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="display-4">Fluid jumbotron</h1>
            <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Jumbotron End-->

    <div class="container">
        <p>What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
            the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
            it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
            remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
            Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
            of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable
            content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
            distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.
            Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a
            search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over
            the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). Where does it come from?
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin
            literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney
            College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage,
            and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum
            comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by
            Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance.
            The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard
            chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33
            from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied
            by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Where can I get some? There are many variations
            of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour,
            or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum,
            you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators
            on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet.
            It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate
            Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected
            humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you used fixed-top in you nav class

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light fixed-top">
```

which makes it to cause the problem.

- You can remove it but then your nabvar won't be fixed on top
- or you can add this css class

`.jumbotron{
            margin-top: 80px;
        }`

better wrap the whole other sections except the navbar in .wrapper{margin-top: 80px;} and your don't have to worry about it ever

Comment: .jumbotron{ margin-top: 80px;} is to much margin-top and leaves a 4px gap between his elements.

Comment: well you have to adjust it according to your navbar height. I didn't know the exact height. you know it. I just showed you the way I fixed the problem in my case

Comment: This worked, thanks a million :) I did think I had tried margins, but obviously not :P

Comment: well now you know what to do when this problem occurs in future

Answer (score 1):

if you make `.navbar` position relative and `.jumbotron-fluid` position relative, this will solve your issue. i would read up on position [here](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp) as this knowledge is invaluable when working in front end code

see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfxdebvs/) with the implemented position:relative on the above mentioned classes

Comment: This didn't actually work for me, not sure why - I will read up on that post and thank you for reaching out. 
.navbar, .jumbotron{
    position: relative;
}

Comment: strange, as i used your exact code in the above jsFiddle with the addition of the mentioned position relative classes to your internal stylesheet. works perfectly in the fiddle. if you post your attempt using this method i can trouble shoot